# Using/Obtaining SMS short code for application

Tags: android, iphone, sms

I have searched google and have not found the answer I was looking for only bits and pieces. I would like to create an application where a user could text a SMS shortcode number with a certain string of text "example: `IN`" which would then run a command on a server if it matches a specific keyword. Basically it would update a database and then send a message back to the user. My questions are how do I obtain a SMS Short code number? How do I link that with a server? What programming language is the most efficient and effective for accomplishing the task? I have a little bit of programming experience in "HTML, JavaScript, PHP and C" and am willing to learn more languages if required. If someone could answer these questions for me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twilio offers this](http://www.twilio.com/sms/shortcodes) along with their other telephony services. I haven't actually used their SMS service, but I've heard good things about the company in general.

Comment: HOLY!! $3K every 3 months for a shortcode no thanks haha. I wonder if there is a way to just do this with a normal seven digit cellphone number?

Answer (score 2):

For less than 1/100 of the price of a dedicated shortcode, you can start with a ["shared shortcode" provider like TextMarks](http://www.TextMarks.com/api/).
TextMarks owns the "41411" shortcode, and you can lease keywords on it for use with your own applications.

You configure a callback URL, and any incoming SMS messages starting with your keyword get routed to your own web server as HTTP requests.  If you respond with anything, your message even goes back to the user as another SMS response.

More info:

- [TextMarks SMS auto-responder API overview](http://www.TextMarks.com/api/sms-auto-response/)

[Disclosure: I built a large portion of the TextMarks API! Ask me anything.]

Answer (score 1):

You will need a SMS server which is not very common. So you should look for providers like [SMSMode](http://www.smsmode.com/ms/index.jsp?lang=en) or [Essendex](http://www.esendex.us/). But you'll have to pay to receive and send SMS.